# How to automatically update a "status" field depending on data in other fields in access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have little to no experience with access. However, I have managed to create a small recruitment database. I have no experience in coding so please be patient with me!

I am trying to get the status of the candidate to update automatically depending on what stage they are at of the recruitment process. (this may have been answered before but hours of searching i have come up with nothing)

Below i have listed the tables within the database and what field would indicate what status they are at. **The tables are in bold and the fields are in []. What the status should be is in " ".**

I have the following tables:
**Candidate info** - This is where the [Status] field is located.

**Pre-interview**
[Screening date] would suggest this candidate is in "Pre-Interview" State and I have another column which says [interview] This is a yes or no field. If yes, Status would change to "interview". If no, status should change to "closed - NFA(Failed Screening)"

**Interview** - if in the field [interview date] has been entered the status should remain as "interview" but if another field called:

[Result] = Fail. Status should change to "Closed - NFA (failed interview)"
[Result] = Cancelled. Status Should change to "Closed - NFA (Interview Cancelled"
[Result] = Yes & [Interview Priority] = Low - Status should be "Talent Pipeline"
[Result] = Yes & [interview Priority] = Fast Track - Status should be "fast track".

**Onboarding**
If the field [date financial approval requested] has a date then the status should change to "In Approval"
Another field called [Approved] = Yes then state should be "Offer Extended" otherwise "Closed - NFA (Offer Declined)"
If it is approved and another field [Result of Contract offer] = Accepted then status should be "Start Date Set" if declined then status should be "Closed - NFA (Offer Declined)"

**Deployment**
If field [Deployment Date] has a date in it then status should be "Deployment Date Set" otherwise it should state "On Bench"
If the date entered in "deployment date set" has passed then the status should change to "Deployed".

I really hope the above has made sense. I have literally no idea how to implement this and any ideas or help will be much, much appreciated.

Please let me know if further information is required.

Many thanks in Advance!!
Asmaar

Comment: Take a look at event macros for after update. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/after-update-macro-event

Comment: Since status is a calculated value (data dependent on other data), don't save it, just calculate when needed. You have a lot of conditionals to determine status, probably more than can be handled with a simple expression in query and will need a VBA custom function. You have conflicting criteria. How can Status ever be "On Bench" if those other fields have value? Whether or not you save calculated status value, need to program decision logic to arrive at status.